# SML: why the return type is unit?

Tags: sml, smlnj

So I have wrote a function (I will describe it briefly to avoid confusion)

```
   fun function1 (l, a1,a2, suma, b2, sumb, d)   = 
   while(a1<a2 andalso k>d) do
     let 
       
       val k = Real.fromInt(a2-a1)
       val suma = suma - Real.fromInt(List.nth(l, a1))  
       val sumb = sumb - Real.fromInt(List.nth(l, b2)) 
       val a1 = a1+1
       val b2 = b2-1
   in  
       if suma<0.0 andalso ( (~sumf)/(N*k) )>1.0 andalso k>d
           then  k
       else if sumb<0.0 andalso ((~sumb)/(N*k))>1.0 andalso k>d
           then  k
       else d   
   end;
```

The system says this:

```
val function1 = fn : int list * int * int * real * int * real * real -> unit
```

**`I don't get the return type. I want to return a real like d & k . Why it's unit??`**

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]. All of the ways I can think of to fill in the `...`s in your code would either lead to the result type `real` or to a type error.

Comment: okay i updated it.

Comment: But -- you didn't update it to be a [mcve]. When I try to run the code you posted, it throws several errors about unbound variables. In any event -- a `while` loop has type `unit`. It is seldom needed in SML. Its use suggests that you are thinking imperatively rather than functionally.

Comment: @i am sorry you are right i did not write values as i have in my program for the variables. So you are saying that a while loop always returns unit if I got it right?

Comment: Yes, `while` is designed to repeatedly do an action, not compute a value. It is part of the imperative sub-language of SML. The code that you give looks more like Java than idiomatic SML.

Comment: the truth is that I haven't found for this particular problem   a solution to fully take advantage of ml tools like pattern matching and other... because I need to do something like a loop (my functional programming thinking is not that strong yet)

Comment: What is your function trying to compute? That might others in giving suggestions about alternative approaches.